# React Native: Error 500 when loading custom component

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to make a custom component for a test app, but I'm getting this error when loading the app from Expo:

> Uncaught error: java.lang.Exception: Bundle return code: 500.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrycC.jpg

(not enough reputation to post image, sorry)

My project structure is basically as follows:

- /TestApp

  - App.js
  - /src

    - /components

      - CustomButton.js
      - CustomButton.style.js

CustomButton.style.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  buttonContainer: {
    width: 100,
    height: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    border: '1px solid white',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

CustomButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './CustomButton.style';

export default class CustomButton extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.props = props;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          {this.props.title}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import CustomButton from './src/components/CustomButton';

export default class TestApp extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <CustomButton/>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is when I try to import the custom component, because the app loads when I comment the line. I've read some questions about this, and it usually happens because the path is incorrect, though I can't figure out what's wrong with my path.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import for the `StyleSheet` is wrong in your code, it must be imported from `react-native`

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
```

Also `constructor` is not preceeding with a `super` class

You need to add

```
constructor(props){
    super(props) <== If you want to access props
    this.props = props;
  }
```

The styles are also not valid, since there is no property for `border`, you may check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed it, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've made an edit with an imgur link (https://i.imgur.com/wRTxa8V.jpg) since I can't post images (not enough reputation).

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you for the answer. It worked!